# How to create perspective images from one that's flat in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

I'm looking to create something like the image above. Essentially I want to take a flat image and change the angle and add some DOF. Anyone know how to do this **in photoshop?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Edit` > `Transform` > `Distort`, move the handles to distort the image, then use the Blur tool set to a large brush size - and blur the near and far edges.

[image: Example of perspective and depth of field effect]